# Trying to retrieve tweets from twitter, but unidentified error occurs

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I am trying to retrieve tweets from twitter on a full archive basis. However, I finally managed to work things out on my developer page, but the code seems to stumble upon an error that I can not find anywhere on the internet. This is my code without my tokens:

```
install.packages("RCurl")

library("RCurl")

install.packages("rtweet")

library("rtweet")

consumer_key <- ".."
consumer_secret <- ".."
access_token <- ".."
access_secret <- ".."
app <- "..."

token = rtweet::create_token(app,consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_secret)

dataBTC1 <- search_fullarchive("Bitcoin", n = 1000, env_name = "Tweets", fromDate = "201501010000")
```

And this is the error I get:

Error in tweet(x$quoted_status) :
Unidentified value: edit_history, edit_controls, editable.
Please open an issue and notify the maintainer. Thanks!

Literally no idea what it means and how to solve it if possible. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These errors occur because the R package you are using (rtweet) does not "know" about the three new fields that were added to the Tweet object when the new editable Tweets feature was released. You will need to [ask the rtweet maintainers](https://github.com/ropensci/rtweet/issues) (as it mentions in the error message) to enable support for these fields in their library, or find an alternative way to call the API.

Comment: Thanks! I have posted a new thread on Github. Hopefully they can help me out. I'm working on my thesis and am in need of retrieving tweets past the 6-9 days and more from years ago. Do you know if Python's package are up to date for such things?